# Read File into an Array? - MIPS

Tags: arrays, function, assembly, mips

I'm not sure exactly how to tackle this, but I need to code a function that takes in an *address for the start of an array, address of a file name, and the maximum number for bytes to read.* I'm not even sure if my code works or not, but this is what I have, I just don't think this is reading in the values into an array form. If someone can clarify what exactly syscall 14 does, i'd appreciate it.

```
fill_the_array:
la $t0, 0($a0) #base address of the array in memory
la $t1, 0($a1) #address of the filename in memory
move $t2, $a2 # maximum number of bytes to read from the file into memory 

#open file
li $v0, 13      #syscall for opening the file
la $a0, 0($t1)    #address of file name
li $a1, 0       #read in data
li $a2, 0       #mode is ignored
syscall         #open the file descriptor
move $s0, $v0 # file descriptor

move $a0, $s0 # file descriptor
move $a1, $t0 #address into input buffer (the address for the array???)
move $a2, $t2 # maximum number of bytes
li $v0, 14
syscall

#close the file
li $v0, 16 
move $a0, $s0
syscall

jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

> If someone can clarify what exactly syscall 14 does, i'd appreciate it.

```
Name             Number   Arguments                       Returns
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
read from file   14       $a0 = file descriptor           $v0 contains number of characters read (0 if end-of-file, negative if error).
                          $a1 = address of input buffer
                          $a2 = maximum number of characters to read
```

So it reads a number of bytes (at most `$a2` bytes) from a file, and stores them in memory starting at the address given in `$a1`. The actual number of bytes read is then returned in `$v0`.

If you need to check whether or not your code works, run it in a simulator like MARS or SPIM. They both have memory viewers. They also let you single-step through your code and set breakpoints, in case your code isn't working as expected and you need to find out where things go wrong.